# Mono app Windows 10 compatibility

Tags: c#, windows, mono, windows-10

I have mono application that compiled on windows 7 x86. It works on any other windows 7 system even without mono runtime. But i can't run it on any Windows 10 system.
This is GTK# app. I'm not using anything except Mono and GTK#. No IL repacking.
Tried to google and didn't find any answer. 
No logs, no errors. Simply can't run it. What's the problem?

Comment: Console app? Windows Forms? What about debugging in Win10?

Comment: @fiorebat GTK# app, can't debug in win 10 because don't have it on my computer right now.

Comment: Hi, are you using a straightforward build, no ILMerge/ILRepack'ing etc?

Comment: "Cannot run it" is not a good description of the problem. Any more info you can share such as Windows event log in Application category?

Comment: As soon as possible, i will add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a host of things, but if you're not doing something unusual like IL repacking then I would start with looking at simple things like checking whether you have GTK# installed on your Windows 10 box and whether your mono compiled application is compatible with the .NET version on that box etc. I have had this behaviour when using ILMerge / ILRepack, hence my earlier comment/question, but compatibility is more likely the issue.

Comment: I'm using GTK# and Mono as part of program distribution. On Windows 7 without Mono or Gtk# it works perfectly. Thats not a problem, i think original problem is compatibility as you said.

Comment: If it's a GTK# app then it won't run without the GTK# libraries. You can install the GTK# libraries without installing mono (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/installer-for-net-framework/) and have .NET run them, which is possibly what you are doing on Win 7 (?). If it's GTK# and it's running then the libraries must be present....